# Why does my sprite not showup in the scene in the Godot engine even though I have created it using the script?

Tags: c#, game-engine, godot

```
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class PlayerCharacter : Sprite2D
{
    // Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
    public override void _Ready()
    {  
        Sprite2D Player = new Sprite2D();
        Texture spriteTexture (Texture)ResourceLoader.Load("res://Main/Assets/ball.png");
        Player.Texture = (Texture2D)spriteTexture;
        Player.Position = new Vector2(100,100);
    }


    public override void _Process(double delta)
    {
    }
}
```

This is my code to display the sprite.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk3QI.png)

This is what shows up

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new instance to the scene tree by using `AddChild`. For example:

```
AddChild(Player);
```

In this case, the `Node` where you created it will be the parent of the new `Node`.

It is unclear to me which `Node` you want to be the parent of the new one. For example you might want it as a sibling of the `Node` where you created it:

```
GetParent().AddChild(Player);
```

It might be important where you add it because by default, `Node`s move with their parent (i.e. when the parent moves, its children move).

---

Anyway, I see you are doing this in `_Ready` which makes me think that perhaps you could add the `Node` in the editor instead of doing it from code.

Consider also creating an scene (a `.tscn` or `.scn` file), load it and instantiate it (yes, you would still have to add the instance to the scene tree by using `AddChild`).

I don't know what you are doing, but just in case, I'll give you a heads up: `Sprite2D` is only concerned with graphics, not physics (so it won't detect collisions). Consequently we would usually use a physics body with a graphics node as a child (so the graphics node move when the physics body moves).

Comment: Hello thank you so much for the help i will try it out.I am unsure on whether I should attach this script to load the sprite on the Sprite2D node or to the parent CharacterBody Node ?